# JavaScript - Calculate elapsed time between two dates?

Tags: javascript, html, function, elapsedtime

If I had a form that allowed for someone to select any start date (MM/DD/YYY) and any end date (MM/DD/YYYY), how would I calculate the difference between those two selected dates?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxSg4.png)

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you for all your help.

```
<script>
    var date1 = new Date();
    var date2 = new Date();

    var diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    var msec = diff;
    var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
    msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
    var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
    msec -= ss * 1000;

    function timeElapsed() {
    var text = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    document.getElementById("elapse").innerHTML = text;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that *date1* and *date2* likely have exactly the same time value, so the difference is 0ms. Try passing some parameters to create dates for different moments in time, e.g. `new Date(2018,9,19)`.

Comment: @RobG thank you. Will that still work if the user is the one entering their choice of date?

Comment: @RizzaEsguerra—yes.

Answer (score 0):

yes

```
  let diff =  (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())
```

will give you differece

convert it with

```
let diffInDay = diff / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. However I'm still confused on how to write out the code and have the answer show up after clicking the button.